# How to Vectorize this Matlab Function?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to speed up a Matlab function by vectorization.  The function looks like this:

```
function tradePL = tradepl(signals, periodPL)
tradePL = [];
PL = 0;
for i = 2:length(signals)-1
    if signals(i) == 0
        if signals(i-1) ~= 0          % trade ends
            PL = PL + periodPL(i+1);  
            tradePL = [tradePL,PL];  
            PL = 0;
        end
    else
        if signals(i-1) == signals(i)  || signals(i-1) == 0
            PL = PL + periodPL(i+1);
        else
            tradePL = [tradePL, PL];
            PL = periodPL(i+1);
        end
    end
end
```

Which works as follows:

```
signals = {0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0};
periodPL = {0, 0, -0.0150, 3.0000, 0.9850, -0.0150, 1.0000, 
   1.0000, -3.0150, 0};
tradePL = tradepl[signals, periodPL]

{2.985,1.97,-2.015}
```

What the function is trying to do is group and total the periodic PLs into trades, which span periods of varying lengths.

A trade at period t is triggered by a signal at period t-1, and terminates when the sign of the signal changes. In the given example, there are three (pairs of) sign changes in signals, and therefore three trades. I want to group and add the periodPL values so that the total for each group is the PL for the corresponding trade.

Comment: Why do you need this vectorized? Loops haven't been slow in MATLAB for a long time now. If it's too slow, then start by replacing `tradePL = [tradePL,PL]` with `tradePL(end+1) = PL`, which is a much faster way to grow the array. If then it's still too slow, pre-allocate a `tradePL` array that is large enough, then trim it after the loop (avoiding array growing altogether). Obviously you prefer this simpler code to the obtuse "vectorized" code in the answer below. Readability and maintainability are very important.

Comment: " Loops haven't been slow in MATLAB for a long time now. "  I havent use Matlab for some time, Chris.  It's quite possible that what you say is correct.  Generally, I am finding Matlab much faster than I thought it would be.  Furthermore, I am not noticing a tremendous different in the speed of mex versions of functions, in the way that there used to be.  When did Matlab get a speed upgrade, I wonder?

Comment: I think MATLAB first got a JIT in 2002 or so. They have been steadily improving on it since. In 2016 they completely rebuilt it (see [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/)). So MATLAB has been getting faster and faster over the last 20 years. Vectorization is often not really useful any more, except if it simplifies the code (i.e. use `sum()` rather than a loop that adds up individual elements).

Answer (score 2):

I vectorized your code by using `cumsum` as follows:

```matlab
function tradePL = tradepl_vec(signals, periodPL)
    % Get trigger indices for each trade
    trigger_idx_a = find(signals(2:end)~=0  & signals(1:end-1)==0) + 1; % start trade
    trigger_idx_b = find(signals(2:end)~=0 & abs(diff(signals))==2) + 1; % start and end trade
    trigger_idx_c = find(signals(2:end-1)==0  & signals(1:end-2)~=0) + 2; % end trade
    
    % extract start and end indices for cumultative sums
    start_idx = sort([trigger_idx_a, trigger_idx_b]);
    end_idx = sort([trigger_idx_b, trigger_idx_c]);
    % catch additional start and end indices
    if end_idx(1) <= start_idx(1)
        start_idx = [2, start_idx];
    end
    if length(start_idx) ~= length(end_idx)
        start_idx = start_idx(1:end-1);
    end
    % calculate sums of grouped trades
    periodPL_sums = cumsum(periodPL);
    tradePL = periodPL_sums(end_idx) - periodPL_sums(start_idx);
end
```

I extracted three conditions from your `if`-statements, that start and/or end a trade:

- When the signal is not 0 and was 0 before, a trade is started at the next index
- When the signal switches from -1 to 1 or 1 to -1 the trade ends at the current index and a new trade starts at the next index
- When the signal is 0 and wasn't 0 before the trade ends at the next index

This computes the desired output for the given example and behaves the same for a few additional sequences I could think of.

Note: It is possible, that the Code finds an additional start index at the end of the `signals` vector, which is being ignored, or an end index at the beginning of the code, where a start index is implied by the given code, so I added it, too.

The trade groups of `periodPL` compared to `signals` is shown here.

[Plot of signals and grouped periodPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUDOo.png)

I'm not sure, whether this is the intended behavior (I would expect the groups shifted by one index to the left), but it is the behavior of the given code, so I expect, that I don't quite understand the intention behind the code. If not, the shift could be adjusted by changing the additions in the rows for the `trigger_idx_` variables.

**Edit**: I had to correct the condition to check if the first end index is before the first start index. Also, your code doesn't find a zero-crossing from the second to last to the last index, if intended, the trigger_idx_b should only take into account the indices to `end-1` instead of `end`.
Regarding the speed of the code, for a random signal with a length of 10^6 the function above is approximately 7 times faster than the original function and 3.5/3 times faster than the suggested optimizations in the comments using `tradePL(end+1) = PL;` or preallocating `tradePL` with the size of `signals` and removing unused elements with `tradePL(j:end) = [];`. But since even your original code takes only a little over half a second for my laptop, I don't know, if speed should be your biggest concern, as pointed out in the comments.